# Unable to search a SQL database under ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've added a **LINQ-SQL link** in my website to make objects and after that, I'm trying to write the neccesary code to search into a database.

In my case I am trying to **display a column value assigned to another of other column into a DATABASE using the following code** but I can't:

```
Palabras_Definiciones quintanaserena = new Palabras_Definiciones(); // LINQ

if (searchInput.Attributes["value"] == quintanaserena.palabra)
{
    Label1.Text = quintanaserena.definición;
}
```

**Am I doing anything wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above, you are not doing any request to the database. You only created the object that has the same definition as your database table.
To query your database, you need to do a query over your DataContext (usually the name of your .dbml file).
MSDN has a good web page to show sample of query. You might want to take a look there: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b
Your query would probably look like:

```
palabrasDataContext dcPalabras = new palabrasDataContext();    //palabrasDataContext would be the name of the DataContext you generated
Palabras_Definiciones quintanaserena = (from palabras in palabrasDataContext
                                        where palabras.palabra == searchInput.Attributes["value"]   //palabra is the name of the column
                                        select palabras).FirstOrDefault();                 //Using firstorDefault here if you have only one definition per word

if(quintanaserena != null)       //FirstorDefault returns null if the resultset was empty
{
    label1.Text = quintanaserena.definición;
}
```

Comment: sorry it should have been palabras.palabra (same word after the from and the column name). I corrected it in the example

Comment: Amm. This code works well and fine but I want to know how can I add **a conditional loop to check if the term is found in the database**.

Comment: what do you mean by "check if the term is found in the database"?

Comment: I wanted to know how to write an algorythm to check if the term (item) is found in the database but I already know how to do that (adding an "else" loop). Thanks.